# How does one install the PECL inotify extension for PHP7?

Tags: php, php7, inotify

I'm trying to get [Inotify](http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php) working on PHP7. I've installed the required packages:

```
sudo apt install php php-dev
```

And installed Inotify with Pecl:

```
sudo pecl install inotify
```

But it doesn't work:

```
$ php -r "var_dump(function_exists('inotify_init'));"
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 7):

Pecl installs inotify to `/usr/lib/php/20151012/inotify.so` and this isn't loaded by any default php.ini. So it needs to be added, by creating `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/inotify.ini` with the following contents:

```
extension=inotify.so
```

And then running `sudo phpenmod inotify`

Now it works:

```
$ php -r "var_dump(function_exists('inotify_init'));"
bool(true)
```